# Eziriz - Intellilock invalid licence problem

Tags: .net, intellilock

Unfortunately we used intellilock to licence our software.

A licence file works in everywhere but not in one of our clients. It's a really stupid situation because we have no inner knowledge or way to debug the licencing component:

- Intellilock doesn't answer support emails, they don't have a phone number either
- Intellilock exceptions are obfuscated so we can't debug it (*actually it doesn't even throw exception*)

Has anyone experienced a similar problem? Licence was locked with day + date. I checked the "New Trial Period" to ensure an old licence would not cause a problem.

Now we stuck with a licensing component without support and a client who cannot use our software. Any ideas other than buying a new licencing component and integrating it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An old license lock was in affect when I use the new licence without activating that lock.  I used generated a new licence by activating it and overriding the property and it finally worked.

Comment: I ran in the same problem with Intellilocks. What do you mean by "activating it and overriding the property"? I do not see relative option in the license generator tab...